# Create struct objects in a for loop

Tags: c#

I have some troubls to create an struct object in for loop.
I have an UserData Struct:

```
  public struct UserData
{
     public string userID { get; set; }

     public string userProjects { get; set; }
     public string userAccess { get; set; }
    //private List<UserData> list;
    public UserData(string id,string project,string access):this()
    {
        this.userID = id;

        this.userProjects = project;
        this.userAccess = access;
      //  list = new List<UserData>();
    }
```

}

So in another Class I try to make a List of my UserData Struct in a for loop:

```
Class ReadUserData
{
  private List<UserData> userdata;
  for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
        {
            userdata = new List<UserData>() { new  
              UserData(userID[j.ToString()],
              userProject[j.ToString()], 
              useraccess[j.ToString()]) };
        }

        var firstuser = userdata.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My Problem is that the count from the userData object is 1. It only create 1 object.
Where is my problem can you help?
Thanks

Comment: It's because you're overwriting the contents of userdata on every loop with a new list.

Comment: Thanks but how can I solve it?

Comment: You really need look up on how to use lists, but on first iteration you should create the list, and after that add to the list

Comment: Why are you using a `struct`? It appears you should be using a `class`.

Comment: Worse, this is a mutable struct. You are really opening up a huge can of hurt.

Answer (score 0):

you must add objects to the list using `Add` method. currently you are overwriting list by putting new list into userdata

```
Class ReadUserData
{
  private List<UserData> userdata = new List<UserData>();// create empty list


  for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
        {
            userdata.Add(new  
              UserData(userID[j.ToString()],
              userProject[j.ToString()], 
              useraccess[j.ToString()])); // add objects to the list at each iteration
        }

        var firstuser = userdata.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[More about List How to Add.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-add)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `List<UserData>` with ONE item and then you are assigning to `userdata` object. You are doing that repeatedly in every iteration, that's why.

Try this instead (create the list outside the loop, and `Add` one item at a time

```
Class ReadUserData
{
  private List<UserData> userdata = new List<UserData>();

  for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
        {
              userdata.Add( new  
              UserData(userID[j.ToString()],
              userProject[j.ToString()], 
              useraccess[j.ToString()]) );
        }

        var firstuser = userdata.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @hamillton123 did this help? Select this or any other answer as the selected answer (green check).